# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "и"? Нужно ли заменить местоимение "его" или у карманов бывают ладони?

Tags: пунктуация, местоимения

Мальчик опустил руку в карман и в следующее мгновение на его ладони оказался камень голубого цвета.

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что местоимение «его» заменяет карман, а не мальчика? Повествование то идёт про мальчика.

Comment: Откуда этот текст?

Comment: Я как раз писала про мальчика:) И про его карман:) Но неожиданно вспомнила про правило, где следует заменять местоимения, если до них идет несколько имен собственных или существительных одного и того же рода. Но ведь и без замены смысл иногда бывает полностью понятен. Или это правило относится только к тем моментам, где может возникнуть очевидное непонимание смысла текста?

Comment: А можете привести правило со ссылкой на источник? Для меня тут непонимания смысла быть не может, потому что у кармана нет ладоней, если только это не какая-то дикая фантастика.

Comment: Мне кажется, имеет значение не только то, что несколько существительных в одно роде, но значения слов.

Comment: Так вот об этом и речь, и вопрос мой был шуточный) Правило найти не смогу, но редакторы иногда просят заменять местоимения на что-то более конкретное. 
Текст мой, я просто привела пример подобных предложений.

Comment: Ясно. Без местоимения мне вариант не нравится: _«**Мальчик** опустил руку в карман, и в следующее мгновение на ладони **мальчика** оказался камень голубого цвета»._

Comment: Конечно, вовсе не благозвучно

Comment: В школе наш учитель (по языку и литературе у нас был УЧИТЕЛЬ!) говорил так: не пишите фраз вроде «Иван подошёл к нашему столу, он явно был навеселе»; конечно, всё тут понятно, но почти всегда кто-нибудь притворяется идиотом и спрашивает: «Кто был навеселе — стол?» И наш учитель был абсолютно прав :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, запятая нужна. Это обычное сложносочиненное предложение, соединенное союзом «и», при отсутствии  трех причин не ставить запятую: когда есть общее сочетание, к которому относятся части сложного предложения; когда части сложносочиненного вопросительные, побудительные или восклицательные; когда части сложносочиненного являются односоставными.
Правильная пунктуация данного предложения следующая: «Мальчик опустил руку в карман, и в следующее мгновение на его ладони оказался камень голубого цвета».

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129071/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-korbett--------).