# "Послышался механический звук..." Сложносочиненное предложение

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Необходимо ли во всех предложениях ставить запятые перед союзом "и" в этом тексте?

> "Он прикоснулся к шкатулке, раздался тихий щелчок и крышка медленно
> начала подниматься. Послышался механический звук и появились стрелки
> часов на деревянном циферблате. Они начали вращаться и каждая в разную
> сторону".

Comment: Всегда было интересно, почему, если речь идет об одном человеке и об одной ситуации, необходимо все равно ставить запятую. Например: Прозвучал тихо голос за его спиной и он обернулся. По смыслу понятно, что речь идет лишь об одном человеке. Голос прозвучал за его спиной и он же обернулся. Если запятая не будет стоять, то от этого не будет потерян смысл предложения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(1) Он прикоснулся к шкатулке, раздался тихий щелчок, и крышка медленно начала подниматься. (2) Послышался механический звук, и появились стрелки часов на деревянном циферблате. (3) Они начали вращаться, **и каждая в разную сторону.***

**Пояснение**

Запятые ставятся перед союзом И во всех случаях.

В предложении (1) **три основы**, бессоюзная и союзная сочинительная связь. Союз И не считается замыкающим, как при однородных членах.

В предложении (2) **две основы**, связь сочинительная союзная (это ССП), запятая ставится.

В предложении (3) вторую часть можно считать **присоединительной конструкцией**, по структуре это неполное предложение: *и каждая из стрелок вращалась в разную сторону*. Союз И — присоединительный.

**Пример из Розенталя:** *Мне с трудом удалось достать этот справочник, **и то на время**.*

[§ 24. Присоединительные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120)

Comment: Что-то мне режет слух "в разную сторону", или это нормально?

Comment: Можно исправить: причем в разные стороны, и каждая в свою сторону.  Так будет правильнее, но почему-то менее художественно. Или мне это кажется?

Comment: ОТВЕТ НА КОММЕНТАРИЙ. Если коротко, то так. Пунктуация основана на трех принципах –  семантическом, структурно-грамматическом и интонационном. Они связаны между собой, как связаны содержание (первый принцип) и форма (второй и третий принцип). Автору нужно выразить определенное содержание, и для этого он подбирает форму (грамматику и структуру). Здесь описаны ДВЕ СИТУАЦИИ, субъекты действия  и сами действия разные – поэтому это ССП, состоящее из двух простых предложений. Естественно, между ними ставится запятая, а пауза в речи чётко обозначена.

Comment: Кстати, структура первой части выглядит неестественно (требуется редактирование, причем по контексту).

Comment: Перенесла комментарий, так как изменения к моему вопросу не отображались на главной странице. Видимо, надо было подождать. Спасибо за ответ, очень все интересно и сложно. Вы могли бы сказать, как могла бы выглядеть первая часть более естественно на ваш взгляд?

Comment: Разве бывает интересно и сложно?  Лучше, когда интересно и просто, а у меня так не получилось. Может, еще кто ответит. Вариант редактирования: Чей-то голос тихо прозвучал за его спиной, и он обернулся.

Answer (score 2):

В предложении: ‟Он прикоснулся к шкатулке — раздался тихий щелчок и крышка медленно начала подниматься” — ставится тире, где я поставил, так как тут бессоюзные следственные отношения. [Ссылка на бессоюзные следственные отношения в справочнике Розенталя.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151)
Второе предложение — ‟Послышался механический звук, и появились стрелки часов на деревянном циферблате” — обычное сложносочиненное без причин убрать запятую.
Третье предложение — ‟Они начали вращаться, и каждая в разную сторону” — тут предложение: ‟каждая в разную сторону” — неполное от ‟каждая вращалась в разную сторону” (с подлежащим ‟каждая” и пропущенным сказуемым в неполном), а следовательно, это сложносочинённая связь без причин убрать запятую.

Comment: В первом предложении стоит запятая вместо тире, так как по ощущениям предполагается спокойное и неспешное повествование, одно действие за другим. Про остальные предложения очень интересно написали, мне тоже не хотелось там ставить запятые. В предыдущем сообщении Sharon ответила по-другому.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467351/Нужна-ли-запятая-перед-союзом-и-Нужно-ли-заменить-местоимение-его-или-у-кар?noredirect=1#comment485360_467351

Comment: Ссылка с вашим ответом к одному из моих прошлых вопросов...

Comment: @Marusya, Вы пишете: "...мне тоже не хотелось там ставить запятые". Так ведь не только Sharon, но и Jim Korbett их ставят.

Comment: Jim Korbett пишет везде "убрать запятую", посмотрите его сообщение.

Comment: Кажется я поняла, первый раз прочитала его ответ таким образом: "это сложносочинённая связь без причин", убрать запятую. Еще подумала, наверное, это какое-то дополнение к правилу)

Comment: @Marusya Jim Korbett пишет: "**...без причин**  убрать запятую". И в самих предложениях она стоит. А вообще, вы знаете... Когда я прочитал ваш вопрос и эти предложения, у меня закралась мысль, что, несмотря на то что в них нет общих частей, которые позволяют не ставить запятую перед *и*, они выглядят однородными и ее (запятую) действительно ставить не хочется (кроме третьего), вопреки правилам. Далеко не всё прописано, и, может быть, в будущем... короче... вот...